# Scanning the entire user input for a matching keyword in Java

Tags: java

So I am stuck trying to find a keyword that matches a sentence that a user input. Instead of entering one string I want to enter an entire sentence and check the sentence for the keyword. Here is some code i worked on but for some reason I can't scan an entire sentence for a matching keyword.

```
input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        if (keywords[i].equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            System.out.println("Found keyword!");
            // TODO: You can optimize this
        }
    }
```

and the list of keywords are

```
 String[] keywords = { "day", "What book", "professor name", "office",
            "hour", "e-mail", "name", "major", "student e-mail",
            "group id", "group name", "lecture", "lecture room",
            "lecture time", "number of lectures", "current lecture",
            "topics of current lecture", "number of test",
            "date of a test", "number of assignments", "sure",
            "current assignment", "due day" };
```

Comment: since my initial answer did not solve it, then I would please ask you to give us a reproductible example. In other words, please tell us the line you write tot he input, or an executable code with hardcoded values that represent the failing use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently storing an entire line of text from the input file and comparing it for equality against your keywords. Assuming that there is more than one word per line, your code will not work.

You have 2 options that I can think of. One is to use the `contains` method on String:

```
input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    if (input.contains(keywords[i])) {
        System.out.println("Found keyword!");
        // TODO: You can optimize this
    }
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to look at the [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class. This allows you to take a sentence and look at each individual word.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String[] keywords = {"day", "What book", "professor name", "office",
            "hour", "e-mail", "name", "major", "student e-mail",
            "group id", "group name", "lecture", "lecture room",
            "lecture time", "number of lectures", "current lecture",
            "topics of current lecture", "number of test",
            "date of a test", "number of assignments", "sure",
            "current assignment", "due day"};

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            if (input.contains(keyword)) {

                System.out.println("Found keyword match  , " + keyword);

            }
```

try the above code , it checks whether your input sentence contains any of the given keyword.